# docker-compose Not Working With gcloud: Cannot Find OpenSSL

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, gcloud

After following the setup instructions for the Artifact Registry in the gcloud CLI, whenever I use docker-compose and I try to fetch an image from a registry, this stack trace appears:

```
Pulling **** (europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/****/****/****:latest)...
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: /tmp/_MEIsEW5sl/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import arg_parsers
    from googlecloudsdk.core import log
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config
    from oauth2client import client
    from oauth2client import transport
    import httplib2
    from httplib2.python3.httplib2 import *
    import ssl
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    /usr/bin/python3

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 512, in run
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/docker-credential-gcloud', 'get']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "docker/credentials/store.py", line 93, in _execute
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Credentials store docker-credential-gcloud exited with "".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 126, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1070, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1066, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 615, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 356, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1267, in pull
  File "compose/progress_stream.py", line 99, in get_digest_from_pull
  File "compose/service.py", line 1234, in _do_pull
  File "docker/api/image.py", line 396, in pull
  File "docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
  File "docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
  File "docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Credentials store docker-credential-gcloud exited with "".')
[14339] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I honestly can't understand what is going wrong there. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My system has OpenSSL 1.1.1f installed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, there is [a issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5930) in docker-compose that gives some solutions to this problem. It seems that a Google Cloud SDK update broke the fix that the docker team had issued. A temporary solution given [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5930#issuecomment-724525064) fixed my issue:

```sh
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well!  I'm using WSL2 with docker and trying to `docker-machine` pull some images.

Comment: This also solved my issue on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 47):

This fixes the issue for Python 3:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

There is a detailed explanation in this [upstream comment](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5930#issuecomment-386157359) on why the resolved `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is incorrect and needs changing.

Comment: This fixed my issue on WSL2

Comment: Fixed my issue on Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Fixed my issue on PopOs 21.04

Comment: It worked with Ubuntu 20,4

Comment: Fixed my issue on gcp cloudshell

Answer (score 0):

I was using gcloud-sdk 301.x.x and got the same issue. A workaround solution is to downgrade the google-cloud-sdk version.

```
sudo apt install google-cloud-sdk=297.0.1-0
```

A related github issue [here](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/128)